# Upgrading Ember from 1.13 to 2.3 breaks fastboot why?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I've upgraded my ember app from `1.13` to `2.3` and installed `ember-cli-fastboot` addon. But after upgrading this plugin isn't not working, why? I created a new project with version `2.18` and repeated the same installation. Fastboot works fine. I can't start my project from zero. Because it's working on the server. I can only upgrade my ember step by step.

Ember version:

```
ember: 2.3.2
ember-cli: 3.8.1
node: 10.15.2
os: linux x64
```

Build info:

```
Slowest Nodes (totalTime => 5% )              | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
LessCompiler (1)                              | 681ms               
Rollup (3)                                    | 604ms (201 ms)      
Babel: ember-data (2)                         | 367ms (183 ms)      
Babel: chat (3)                               | 250ms (83 ms)       
Babel: ember-cli-fastboot (1)                 | 213ms               
Package /assets/vendor.js (1)                 | 190ms
```

package.json

```
"broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.2.0",
"ember-ajax": "^5.0.0",
"ember-cli": "^3.8.1",
"ember-cli-app-version": "^3.2.0",
"ember-cli-babel": "^7.5.0",
"ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
"ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
"ember-cli-fastboot": "^2.0.4",
"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.1",
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
"ember-cli-less": "^2.0.1",
"ember-cli-qunit": "^4.4.0",
"ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
"ember-cli-sri": "^2.0.0",
"ember-cli-stripe": "~0.4.0",
"ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
"ember-cookies": "^0.3.1",
"ember-data": "^2.3.0",
"ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.2",
"ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
"ember-fetch": "^6.5.0",
"ember-inflector": "2.2.0",
"ember-legacy-views": "emberjs/ember-legacy-views#master",
"ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.0",
"ember-resolver": "^5.1.3",
"loader.js": "^4.0.0"
```

Comment: What does your `package.json` look like? Please explain what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: plugin isn't working ? what type of error are you facing ?

Comment: I supplemented the question

Comment: fastboot does not show errors

Comment: If there are no errors, how isn't it working?

Comment: I’ve almost run it already, but I’m still having less problems, now it works only when all third-party libraries are disabled

Answer (score 0):

If you have just installed Fastboot for the first time, you are probably hitting errors with some of your code or one of your addons that expects to be running in the browser. IC-Ajax could be your problem but we’ll need more detail about any errors you see to help further.

Fastboot *does* work with Ember 2.3 however ...

Comment: A few days of work on this problem, I launched a fastboot, but the following work arose, app.import ('path / to / jquery.js'); - gives an error and does not compile. Only when you delete it.